# Is there a way to block users?

Tags: discussion

There are users on this site that are poisionong the site for me. How can I block them?

I've tried flagging their comments but there is no response, and my notifications are spammed with their activity.

Comment: If you genuinely think someone is harassing you, then make a formal complaint about it. As commented on one of the answers below, blocking a user is fraught with issues that are likely to make your life more difficult.

Comment: @Phil I'm asking about how to block users to try to avoid whatever issues there are with how people get treated. It's not that they are harassing me specifically, just inconsistent yet abrasive behavior that I would rather not witness so I don't have the temptation to respond to it. Because if I do, they will use it as an excuse to suspend my account.

Comment: @GMNoob If they are really toxic to the site, and not just to you personally (or if they are *abusive* to you, which is even worse) then consult a moderator about taking action against them for their behavior.  Otherwise, sorry but they've got as much right to be on the site as you do.

Answer (score 11):

No. There isn't. This is by design: if a user is behaving badly, it is imperative that the moderators are informed (via flags) and address the situation. Be aware that moderators would tend to contact users privately in these situations rather than making a spectacle of them.

It would also be unhealthy if users were able to squelch valid criticisms using such a blocking function - remember, many others may read these posts as the years roll by, and if there is a problem or a needed clarification then it is important that it is pointed out.

Comment: It's by design that a couple people get to harrass someone off the site?!?

Comment: See my edit, please @GMNoob.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, there is a way to block/ignore users, however its a browser plugin script, rather than something which works on all devices.

[Ignore Users Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script)

Comment: Use at your peril. If you ignore someone who's requesting clarification, you might be left having no idea why your question's getting closed or what other people are responding to. There's reasons the site doesn't implement such a feature - it winds up damaging to you, and the resulting mess is damaging to the site.

Comment: @doppelgreener My questions will get closed by the same people for the same reasons no matter if I see the conversation or not. Better to not know whats happening than to have my day ruined trying to jump through hoops.

Comment: If you see the process of crafting on-topic questions as "jumping through hoops" and resent that, [you may be approaching it wrong](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/is-trivia-on-topic/4808#comment11366_4808). Resisting learning how to use the site well and making a lot of persecuted noise and passive-aggressive meta posts when you need to improve a question does not make *friends*.

Comment: yes, this is something I need to help me take a time out from responding to people I want to argue with. I often can't help but reply to someone who is "Wrong on the internet" when I should not.
Obviously not good to use for days at a time, but for a afternoon. +q1